# Can you explain anyone,how inner query and outer query is working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

***I want to know how inner and outer query is working*?**

Please explain me below query

```
 update jobgrade set HIGHSAL=6000 
 where GRADE in(select grade from JOBGRADE where grade='B');
```

Comment: That query doesn't make sense. Can simply be replaced by `update jobgrade set HIGHSAL= 6000 where GRADE = 'B'`

Comment: Hi @RobbyCornelissen Thank you for your concern,But I know which you explained and doesn't make sense.I want to know how the Inner and Outer query is working.

Comment: there is no any join in your example, why do you put it in your question about joins? Also just doing a little bit of search you'll find plenty of resources answering your question.

Comment: @MátéJuhász You're the only one talking about joins.

Comment: I didn't mention, I'm n't even talking about  their joins Mr.@MátéJuhász

Answer (score 0):

That query says update the `jobgrade` table and set the `HIGHSAL` column to a value of 6000 for every row where the value of the `GRADE` column is in the result set of the `IN` query.

Since the `IN` query is finding all of the rows in `jobgrade` where `grade='B'` it is just going to return a lot of rows with the value `B`. It makes no sense to do this.

You should just do this:

```
UPDATE jobgrade
SET HIGHSAL=6000
WHERE grade='B'
```

because it is the exact same thing.

---

I think I get what you're actually asking.

The query for the `IN` operator won't be affected by the update statement. So if you were updating a field that you filtered on in that query the results would be based on how the table was before the update statement.

I can't find anything to support my theory but I don't believe the query for the `IN` operator is executed more than once and the `WHERE` clause would come before the `UPDATE` clause in the order of operations.

Comment: Okay. That's correct which you told but in stood of grade='B' I am replacing **emp_id='MS101**.I know the simple query Mike, I want to know the flow which one is first will execute where the value is flowing

Comment: *[...] going to return a lot of rows [...]*. Not necessarily. Could be only one or even zero. The result is still the same as when using the simple `WHERE grade='b'` of course.

Comment: I think this is better UPDATE jobgrade
SET HIGHSAL=6000
WHERE grade='B' but i want to know how that is working? need step by step explanation if u dont't mind!  can u please explain me practically.

Comment: @Ranjith 1) you could have easily researched this question yourself; 2) if you use Oracle's `EXPLAIN PLAN` functionality, Oracle will exactly tell you how the query will be executed; and 3) Mike D. did already provide a step-by-step explanation in his answer.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen  May I know what plan functionality and how it will give query is executing help me please and I am using sqldeveloper Robby.

Comment: Why my question is getting negative marks Robby which I asked wrong way.

Comment: @Ranjith You're getting down-voted because your question does not show **any** research effort.

Comment: How can I ask question technically robby and is there anyway to get what I am expecting answer could you tell me please?

Comment: I think I get what you're asking. The query for the `IN` operator won't be affected by the update statement. I can't find anything to support my theory but I don't believe the query for the `IN` operator is executed more than once and the `WHERE` clause would come before the `UPDATE` clause in the order of operations.

Answer (score 0):

On a logical level you have to devide the inner and the outer query in 2 steps.
The outcome of the inner query - in your case it is the `select grade from JOBGRADE where grade='B'` part - will be `appointed` to the `where GRADE in part` in the outer query. Be aware that there are more options to achieve an innner/outer architecture ... or (equivalent) mainquery/subquery architecture. Especially the use of the `in` statement in the outer query is important. You could make use of the `=` clause but then the inner query (~ subquery) *must* yield exactly 1 row; not more en not less. Otherwise the
`ORA-00913: too many values` will be thrown.

Making use of the `in` statement allows the inner query to yield 0 value, 1 value or more then 1 value. In the end the `where GRADE in` will be matched with the value or values that are being retrieved from the inner query.